# OpenUI5 NavContainer inside a Page

Tags: xml, view, sapui5

I'm try to put a NavContainer inside a Page.

But if i try I only get the header of the page and a scrollbar on the left side and nothing else.

My View is in XML and controller for sure in JavaScript.

I already used the Navcontainer in other XMLs but there it work just fine. If i delete the NavContainer under Page content it works fine and i the the other xmlviews.

So my Question is:
Is it possible to put a NavContainer under a Page content?

Or what else can i use? Another "Navigationelement". I tried it already with the Carousel but thats not what i want to do.

Hope you can help me.

My View looks like

```
    <Page showHeader="true" id="startView">
        <customHeader>
            <Bar class="StartseiteCompleteBand">
                <contentMiddle>
                    <Text text="{i18n>Homepage.Titel}" class="StartseiteBarTextMiddle"/>
                </contentMiddle>

            </Bar>
        </customHeader>
        <subHeader>
              <Bar>
             </contentMiddle>
                <contentRight>
                    <Button icon="sap-icon://person-placeholder" class="" text="{i18n>Homepage.Username}"
                            id="openMenuUser"
                            press="handlePressOpenMenu"/>
                </contentRight>
            </Bar>
        </subHeader>
        <content>
      <NavContainer id="navContainer" width="99%">
       <mvc:XMLView viewName="root.spc_management_modern.view.SkeletalStructureGUI"/>
            <lay:Grid defaultSpan="L6 M6 S12" class="GridOnHomepage">

                <lay:Grid id="GridOnHomepage" defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12">
                    <mvc:XMLView viewName="root.spc_management_modern.view.LeftsideHomepage"/>
                </lay:Grid>


                <lay:Grid defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12">
                    <mvc:XMLView viewName="root.spc_management_modern.view.RightsideHomepage"/>
                </lay:Grid>
            </lay:Grid>
       </NavContainer>
        </content>
    </Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it for like more then 3 days and now... i found the solution.
I have to put a page after the navcontainer.
Didn't expect it. 
Like:

```
  <NavContainer width="99%">
            <Page showHeader="false">
                <content>
                    <Button
                            text="To next view"
                            press="handleNav">
                        <layoutData>
                            <FlexItemData growFactor="1"/>
                        </layoutData>
                        <customData>
                            <core:CustomData
                                    key="target"
                                    value="NewTestPlan"/>
                        </customData>
                    </Button>
                    <!--<mvc:XMLView viewName="root.spc_management_modern.view.SkeletalStructureGUI"/>-->
                    <lay:Grid defaultSpan="L6 M6 S12" class="GridOnHomepage">
                        <!--Lädt die linke Seite der Homepage-->
                        <lay:Grid id="GridOnHomepage" defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12">
                            <mvc:XMLView viewName="root.spc_management_modern.view.LeftsideHomepage"/>
                        </lay:Grid>

                        <!--Lädt die rechte Seite der Homepage&ndash;&gt;-->
                        <lay:Grid defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12">
                            <mvc:XMLView viewName="root.spc_management_modern.view.RightsideHomepage"/>
                        </lay:Grid>
                    </lay:Grid>
                </content>
            </Page>
        </NavContainer>
```